# Portable Class Library with async await & GetType().IsValueType

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, portable-class-library

I need the following calls possible within the same portable class library:

```
public class Foobar
{
    void Foo()
    {
        var b = GetType().IsValueType; //<-- 2
    }

    async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Bar<T>() 
        where T : class, IBaz, new()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new List<T>(new[]   //<-- 1
            {
                new T {Qux = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}
            }));
    }

    interface IBaz 
    {
        string Qux { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With the following target frameworks set:

- .net Framework 4.5
- Sliverlight 5
- Windows Phone 8
- .Net for Windows Store apps

I get this build error: 
*Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?*

I tried to install the [bcl](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/) but still get the same error.
And if I remove the Sliverlight target the async works but then I lose the IsValueType prop from the Type class...

Comment: I see no reason at all for that method to be `async`.  Just remove `async`, `await`, and you're done.  Beyond that, I don't even see why that operation needs to happen in a thread pool thread; generating a single GUID is a *very* fast operation.  You'll lose a *lot* more time starting the thread pool thread.

Comment: The example is purely for re-creation of the compile error and is no way indicative of how the solution is structured.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/).